# What to do when in Coombs voting method there two equal weights for candidates to be elimenated?

Tags: decision-theory, voting-theory

I've read about [Coombs method on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coombs%27_method#:%7E:text=Coombs%27%20method%20%28or%20the%20Coombs,has%20a%20majority%20of%20votes.).

I understand that we eliminate candidate with the most last-place votes. But what do we do when, for example, two candidates A and B have equal number of last-place votes?

Which one should be chosen to eliminate?

Comment: Presumably you could look at second-last place votes for A and B and so on until you find one which is less unpopular.  If they are the same at every level, you could then choose one at random

Comment: I did that thing and my final result contradicts the statement that "Coombs rule will always select the Condorcet winner", so I think maybe there is other ways to do so

Comment: "always" is a big word, and that claim is not always true, as pointed out in the Wikipedia talk page.  It may be true in the case of single peaked one-dimensional preferences, but that is not "always"

Comment: Coombs rule will NOT always select the Condorcet winner

Answer (score 0):

I can't find if Clyde Coombs himself suggested a tiebreaker method, but some possibilities are:

- Eliminate *both* of the tied-for-last candidates.
- Flip a coin (or use some other source of randomness) to determine which of the tied candidates to eliminate.
- Eliminate the candidate with the most *second*-to-last place votes (and if *that's* also tied, use the most third-to-last place votes, etc.)
- Fork the vote counting, with one branch eliminating candidate X, ultimately electing winner A; and the other eliminating candidate Y, ultimately electing winner B.  If candidates A and B happen to be the same person, then that's your final winner.  Otherwise, elect the winner of a head-to-head A-B race.